# Recharger un composant Blazor après un OnChange d’un HTML sélectionné

Tags: c#, html, components, blazor, onchange

I cannot reload "ContenuCongelateur" composant after the "update" method found in the onchange of the html select list, Is there a solution?

Thank you from a newbie in Blazor ^^

Index.razor

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 100%" @onchange="Update">
    @if (indexModel?.Congelateurs != null)
    {
        @foreach (var cong in indexModel.Congelateurs)
        {
            <option value="@cong.Num_Congelateur">@cong.Nom_Congelateur</option>
        }
    }
</select>

<hr />

<ContenuCongelateur CongelateurSelected="indexModel.CongelateurSelected"></ContenuCongelateur>

@code {
    CongelateurService congelateurService = new CongelateurService(DBContextConstant.ConnectionString);

    IndexViewModel indexModel;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        indexModel = new IndexViewModel();
        indexModel.Congelateurs = congelateurService.GetListeCongelateurs();
    }

    private void Update(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        indexModel.CongelateurSelected = int.Parse(args.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

ContenuCongelateur.razor

```
<div>
    <div class="card card-body">
        @if (Contenu_Congelateur != null)
        {
            <table class="cell">
                @foreach (var ligne in Contenu_Congelateur)
                {
                    <tr class="cell">
                        @foreach (var cell in ligne.Cells)
                        {
                            <td class="@cell.Class_Color" id="@cell.Num_Boite" @onclick="(() => ChargerBoite(cell.Num_Boite))">
                                @cell.Num_Boite + ":" @cell.Quantite_Restante
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int CongelateurSelected { get; set; }

    CongelateurService congelateurService = new CongelateurService(DBContextConstant.ConnectionString);

    public List<LigneCongelateurDto> Contenu_Congelateur { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Contenu_Congelateur = congelateurService.GetListeDetailleeDispoCongel(CongelateurSelected);
    }
}
```

When updating the component, it must fetch data from the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [StateHasChanged()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.statehaschanged?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to notify Blazor that some information on the page has changed and needs to be redrawn. If you need to update it from an `async` method you would use `await InvokeAsync(()=>StateHasChanged())` instead.

```cs
private void Update(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    indexModel.CongelateurSelected = int.Parse(args.Value.ToString());
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: The OnInitialized() method found in the "ContenuCongelateur" component does not start with StateHasChanged(). 
I add the component code to you in my first message

Comment: Try adding protected `base.OnInitialized();` to your `OnInitialized()` method at the end.

Comment: I have the parameter that is not sending correctly to the child component

Comment: You could try using a property in `ContenuCongelateur` so when `CongelateurSelected`'s value is changed, it calls `StateHasChanged()` on the `ContenuCongelateur` component.

Comment: I succeeded with the OnParametersSet()